# php mysql only returning one row

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a rating website where users rate other people from different schools. Right now I'm trying to do the leaderboard script but I cannot properly get the rating to show. My query is only returning one result. ($helpMe) Essentially I'm declaring the average total since my db doesn't store that, it only stores total number and total votes and divides accordingly.

https://pastebin.com/fVf4B8En here is the main code

I suspect that the culprit is here but not sure how

```
$helpMe = mysql_query("SELECT `rating_number`, FORMAT( (`total_points` /  `rating_number`), 1 ) AS  `average_rating` FROM  `view_rating` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `average_rating` DESC");
while ($ratingRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($helpMe)) {
```

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of sending us to the 3rd party website

Comment: Is there only ONE status that is equal to 1?   If so, that could be why.

Comment: can you show us  `mysql_num_rows()` return result ?

Comment: If you are trying to create an average report, you should be using a GROUP BY query.

Comment: status is equal to 1 for all the rows, its basically if theyre able to vote on it or not so thats not it

Comment: mysql_num_rows() is returning 25 rows, and there are indeed 25 rows in my db

Comment: Use mysql_fetch_array and let me know if you are still getting the error .

Comment: Yeah tried fetch_array and same result

Comment: Can you please add the code that's in that while loop?